# Draw a series of points with vertex array : nothing displayed

Tags: c, opengl, glut, vertex-array

I'm trying for exercise to do the following: there is an array of points, expressed through couples of GLfloats.The user should click in a point in the window to make another points appear.When a point is added, the window shall be redrawn and the points shall display connected with a line.So the user shall be able to draw lines clicking on some locations of the windows.
In this code whenever there's a click I push a point in the vector, but the points is not added, so I just see the gray window (APPLE_GRAY defined in header) without the points.

```
#include <OpenGL/OpenGL.h>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "utility.h"

const int width=500;
const int height=500;

GLfloat* points;
size_t size=100;
int count=0;

void pushPoint(GLfloat x, GLfloat y)
{
    count++;
    if(count>size)
    {
        size+=100;
        points=(GLfloat*)realloc(points,2*size*sizeof(GLfloat));
    }
    points[2*count-2]=x;
    points[2*count-1]=y;
}

void init()
{
    points=(GLfloat*)malloc(2*size*sizeof(GLfloat));
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
    glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(APPLE_GRAY);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor4f(RED);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, points);
    glDrawElements(GL_LINE_LOOP,count,GL_FLOAT,points);
    glFlush();
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(state)
    {
        pushPoint(x, y);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(width,height);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMotionFunc(motion);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure your matrices are right. In init(), it calls glLoadIdentity(), but it never explicitly said for what matrix (here, I might expect MODEL_VIEW). Then there's a glOrtho() which loads an orthographic projection matrix, but it's called *before* glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION). Also, I might start with a fixed array of 2D points until I got rendering working, just to decouple GL issues for memory alloc/dealloc - justathought ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12957136/44729),  `glutInitDisplayMode()` needs to be called *before* `glutCreateWindow()`.

`GL_FLOAT` is not a valid value for `type` in [`glDrawElements()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml#parameters).  Also, `points` is not an index array.

Use [`glDrawArrays()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawArrays.xml):

```
#include <GL/glut.h>

const int width=500;
const int height=500;

GLfloat* points;
size_t size=100;
int count=0;

void pushPoint(GLfloat x, GLfloat y)
{
    count++;
    if(count>size)
    {
        size+=100;
        points=(GLfloat*)realloc(points,2*size*sizeof(GLfloat));
    }
    points[2*count-2]=x;
    points[2*count-1]=y;
}

void init()
{
    points=(GLfloat*)malloc(2*size*sizeof(GLfloat));
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}

void display()
{
    glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3ub(255,0,0);
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, points);
    glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP,0,count);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if(state)
    {
        pushPoint(x, y);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutInitWindowSize(width,height);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("Test");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If I put glutInitDisplayMode before glutCreateWindow, I get a white window and no points are drawn.If I put it in the init method the window is drawn correctly.

Comment: Is that with or without changing `glFlush()` to `glutSwapBuffers()`?